# Angular Test Mock ContentChild

Tags: angular, unit-testing, mocking, angular-content-projection

I want to test an Angular Component and replace the contentChild with a Mock. I followed this guide: https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/angular-unit-testing-viewchild-4525e0c7b756
The guide is for a viewChild, but I thought this could also work for a content Child.

My contentChild has a Observable to which the parent subscribe. If I test the code with the real child, it works. If I mock the child, the test doesn't work. I think the child mock, I query in the test to emit a new value, is a different instance, than the one which the parent subscribed to.

My parent:

```
@Component({
  // tslint:disable-next-line:component-selector
  selector: '[appParent]',
  template: `
    <div>
      <span class="true" *ngIf="display$ | async; else other">True</span>
    </div>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
    <ng-template #other><span class="false">False</span></ng-template>
  `
})
export class ParentComponent implements AfterContentInit {

  @ContentChild(ChildComponent) child!: ChildComponent;

  display$: Observable<boolean>;

  ngAfterContentInit(): void {
    this.display$ = this.child.display$;
  }
}
```

My mock:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  template: '',
  providers: [
    {
      provide: ChildComponent,
      useExisting: ChildStubComponent
    }
  ]
})
export class ChildStubComponent {
  displaySubject = new BehaviorSubject(false);
  display$: Observable<boolean> = this.displaySubject.asObservable();
}
```

And the test:

```
describe('ParentComponentTest', () => {
  @Component({
    template: `
      <div appParent>
        <app-child></app-child>
      </div>
    `
  })
  class TestComponent {
    @ViewChild(ChildStubComponent)
    child!: ChildStubComponent;
  }

  let component: TestComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestComponent>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        TestComponent,
        ChildStubComponent,
        ParentComponent
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(async () => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should find true', () => {
    component.child.displaySubject.next(true);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.true'))).toBeTruthy();
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seams to be, that you get with the view-child not the correct instance. The solution is to get the instance from the child property of the parent component.

```
describe('ParentComponentTest', () => {
  @Component({
    template: `
      <div appParent>
        <app-child></app-child>
      </div>
    `
  })
  class TestComponent {
    @ViewChild(ParentComponent)
    parent!: ParentComponent;
  }

  let component: TestComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestComponent>;

  ....

  it('should find true', () => {
    const childStub = component.parent.child.toArray()[0] as unknown as ChildStubComponent;
    childStub.displaySubject.next(true);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.true'))).toBeTruthy();
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a testing library with mocking features like [ng-mocks](https://ng-mocks.sudo.eu/api/MockComponent)

It provides [`MockBuilder`](https://ng-mocks.sudo.eu/api/MockBuilder) and [`MockComponent`](https://ng-mocks.sudo.eu/api/MockComponent).

Also it has [`MockInstance`](https://ng-mocks.sudo.eu/api/MockInstance) which allows you to mock components methods / properties upfront of their initialization.

I think your case is similar to [How to test a ViewChild / ViewChildren of a declaration](https://ng-mocks.sudo.eu/guides/view-child)

Your test might look like:

```js
describe('ParentComponentTest', () => {
  // keeping ParentComponent as it is and mocking ChildStubComponent
  beforeEach(() => MockBuilder(ParentComponent).mock(ChildStubComponent));

  it('should find true', () => {
    // providing a mock upfront
    const displaySubject = MockInstance(
      ChildStubComponent,
      'displaySubject',
      new Subject(),
    );

    // rendering desired template
    const fixture = MockRender(`
      <div appParent>
        <app-child></app-child>
      </div>
    `);

    // testing behavior
    displaySubject.next(true);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(ngMocks.find('.true')).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Comment: This might work, but in our project we want to install as less packages as possible and we think mocking should be possible without a new package.

Comment: likewise web apps are possible without react and angular :)