# Angular Test: Mocking Viewchild projected component and observable property

Tags: angular, mocking, angular-test, viewchild, angular-mock

I have the following code that I can't mock in my unit tests:

```js
  @ContentChild(CarouselInfoComponent) carouselInfo: CarouselInfoComponent;
  @ContentChild(CarouselComponent) carousel: CarouselComponent;

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.carouselInfo.itemSelected.subscribe((index: number) => {
      this.setActiveCarousel(index);
    });

    this.carousel.itemSelected.subscribe((index: number) => {
      this.setActiveCarouselInfo(index);
    });
  }
```

I have tried something like this:

```js
// spec
// beforeEach
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [ CarouselGalleryComponent, CarouselInfoComponent, CarouselComponent ]
})

// it
spyOn(component.carouselInfo, 'itemSelected').and.returnValue(of(1));
```

But I get the following error:

```
Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'
```

I understand that this is used for methods and basically `itemSelected` is a property of the child component (which, by the way, is a component projected using ng-content).

**Note:**
itemSelected (in both cases) is an instance of EventEmitter en every child component.

Comment: Testing projected content is not responsibility of component. So you simply can move your tests to the component that is filling template.

Answer (score 0):

```
const myCustomSubject = new Subject();
component.carousel.itemSelected = myCustomSubject.asObservable();
```

So if you want to simulate a value emit then you can use:

```
myCustomSubject.next(1);
```

Comment: `itemSelected` is a property of type EventEmitter and not of Subject. I'm refactoring your code: 
```typescript
const myCustomInfo = new EventEmitter<number>();
component.carouselInfo.itemSelected = myCustomInfo;
```

But the result is: 
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'itemSelected' of undefined`

Comment: I tought it was an observable because of the of(1). spyOn(component.carouselInfo, 'itemSelected').and.returnValue(of(1));

Also you can then use component.carouselInfo = { itemSelected: myCustomInfo };
Because it is saying that itemSelected is an undefined value so initialize it as an object inside the mocked event emitter.

Comment: You're right, it's my fault for not specifying. I used of because what I expect is the value emitted by the EventEmitter but in the parent component as a subscribe, I thought I'd mock it like this.

Comment: Doesn't work :( Your solution tells me that I need to define all the other methods and properties of the child component. Can you update your solution in your answer? Can you update your answer? maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, you are correct it wont mock all the functionality of the component, just the event emitter. I found for you another stack overflow answer it might help to you to solve your problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66712667/angular-test-mock-contentchild

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-mocks` and provide mock properties via [`MockInstance`](https://ng-mocks.sudo.eu/api/MockInstance).

```js
MockInstance.scope();

beforeEach(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [
      CarouselGalleryComponent,
      MockComponent(CarouselInfoComponent), // <- mock
      MockComponent(CarouselComponent), // <- mock
    ],
  });
});

it('test', () => {
  MockInstance(CarouselInfoComponent, 'itemSelected', of(1));
  MockInstance(CarouselComponent, 'itemSelected', EMPTY);

  const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CarouselGalleryComponent);
  fixture.detectChanges();
  // now it works.
});
```